# Which configuration of LEDs is optimal with a voltage-current OP-Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes

*I just started sutdying OP-amps today so please be easy on me*. If we have some LED-diodes that need to be lit up with same brightness where they have different knee voltages, which would be the preferred option of configuration to choose?

If they had the same knee voltage I would assume that either **A** or **B** would be pretty much do the same as parallel voltages are equal but wont solve the problem with brightness, right? Then maybe the preferred option is **C** since the voltages would redistribute themselves according to the needs of each diode in a series connection, right?

[image]

Comment: If the LEDs are all different, they all need seperate current limiting resistors, if you want them to consume the same power. What does this question have to do with opamps anyway?

Comment: @Linkyyy, Thanks for the reply! I found this in lecture slides about OP-Amps so no clue why this is there. Ok, so they need current limiting resistors but would the preferred option be series or parallell connection?

Comment: The preferred option would be parallel if the are different, and they need to consume the same power. Series if they have the same forward voltage.

Comment: You do not need an opamp to light LEDs, instead each LED Needs to have its own series resistor tor you to adjust its brightness.

Comment: What exactly is a "voltage-current op amp"? Do you mean a current-feedback amplifier? an OTA? some configuration of a standard op amp?

Comment: Tip: 'op-amp' is an abbreviation of 'operational-amplifier'. It's not an initialisation or proper noun so it doesn't get capitalised.

Answer (score 3):

Connecting two LEDs with different forward voltage specifications in **parallel** will work poorly if at all. The LED with the lower forward voltage will be well illuminated but the one with the higher forward voltage will not. So, your options (A), (B), and (D) are out.

Option (C), with all LEDs in series, will ensure that all LEDs have the same forward **current** but not necessarily the same **brightness**.

If you really need the same brightness then you need to use a different resistor value in **series** with each LED. Then the three LED/resistor combinations can be used in **parallel**.